# The problem in define javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

this is my javascript code which for defining multidimensional array

```
    var array = new Array(2);
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[0] = new Array(4);
    }
    array[0][0] = "name1";
    array[0][1] = "property1";
    array[0][2] = "value1";
    array[0][3] = "0";

    //this is where the error happened
    array[1][0] = "name2";
    array[1][1] = "property2";
    array[1][2] = "value2";
    array[1][3] = "1";
```

but the firebug tell me an error:
**array[1] is not defined**

which I mark in the code above

But the **array[0][]** I could defined,and give them value,

So why the problem happened in this place?Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array[0] = new Array(4)` should be `array[i] = new Array(4)`.

This can be done much more succinctly with array literals though:

```
var array = [
    ["name1", "property1", "value1", "0"],
    ["name2", "property2", "value2", "1"]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is redefining the first member of the array.

```
var array = new Array(2);
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new Array(4);
}
array[0][0] = "name1";
array[0][1] = "property1";
array[0][2] = "value1";
array[0][3] = "0";

//this is where the error happened
array[1][0] = "name2";
array[1][1] = "property2";
array[1][2] = "value2";
array[1][3] = "1";
```

If this is all you are doing you can to it using shorthand syntax

```
var array = [
        [
            "name1",
            "property1",
            "value1",
            "0"
        ],
        [
            "name2",
            "property2",
            "value2",
            "1"
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays.  However, you can have arrays of arrays.  Here's how you can create what you're looking for:

```
var array = [
    ["name1", "property1", "value1", "0"],
    ["name2", "property2", "value2", "1"]];
```

Comment: `JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays`. What did you just create ?

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array then?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Arrays of arrays are *not* the same thing as multidimensional arrays.  A multidimensional array is an array with two fixed dimensions; JavaScript only has one-dimensional arrays which *can contain* other arrays as members.

Comment: In very strict mathematical terms you are right, but the common usage of *"multidimensional array"* means *"array of arrays"*. :)

Comment: Not true even in programming terms.  What is being created is a jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[0] = new Array(4);
}
```

You're always initializing `array[0]` but I think you mean to say `array[i]`